# How to keep dogs out of trash?

Tags: dogs, containment

It's kind of ridiculous that when searching for dog proof trashcans 99% of the ones that come up have a foot pedal that opens them ... I don't know how stupid they think dogs are, but mine figured the pedal out in about a day so there's really nothing "dog proof" about them in the least.

The other option I saw was a touch sensitive ones, but again, not going to take long for the dogs to catch onto that, especially since they'll be poking their face around anyways.

I tried putting something under the pedal to keep it from depressing, and also put a weight on top of the lid so they can't nudge it open (they're pretty tall), but it's a hassle and sometimes I forget and come home to a mess every time ... They never try getting in when I'm at home, even if I'm in the other room, so there's really no way for me to train them.

Does anyone have any other simple tricks that don't require not having a lousy memory or know of any truly dog proof trashcans? Maybe there are some that lock automatically?

Comment: Would it be enough to deactivate the pedal and have you open the lid by hand? Or have your dogs mastered the art of nosing the lid open as well?

Comment: Put the trash can in an inaccessible place:

Comment: @Elmy, no, like I said, i tried putting something under the pedal but they would just lift the lid with their noses %\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The best way to avoid dogs getting into the rubbish when you're not home or overnight (if they are indoors) is to empty the trash before you leave or go to bed. A good habit to generally adopt.
2. One foolproof way to prevent dogs from getting into the rubbish is to put it on a benchtop (providing the dogs are not tall enough to jump up to the bench and grab it off) or place trashcans [inside the kitchen cupboards](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&biw=1387&bih=925&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=BZXxXf_wMLnB3LUP0LyliAY&q=kitchen%20tidy%20inside%20cupboard&oq=kitchen%20tidy%20inside%20cupboard&gs_l=img.3..0l6j0i30j0i5i30l3.37839.43655..43791...0.0..0.1141.5278.5-5j0j2......0....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i67.gfjV3iiD6Xc&ved=0ahUKEwi_h5-B-K7mAhW5ILcAHVBeCWEQ4dUDCAc&uact=5). It's not uncommon to have kitchen tidies inside a kitchen cupboard.
3. If the dogs learn how to open the kitchen cupboard you can put [child locks](https://www.google.com/search?q=child%20lock%20kitchen%20cupboards&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi1wrH8967mAhWX63MBHTv7D_kQ_AUoAXoECA0QAw&biw=1387&bih=925) on the inside of the cupboard and the dogs will not be able to open them. It only allows the cupboard to be open a little and nimble fingers to unlock it.
4. Another way would be to use [child/baby gates](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&biw=1387&bih=925&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=NZXxXbX_EpS_8QOOlKv4CQ&q=baby%20gate&oq=baby%20gate&gs_l=img.3...33452.34620..34834...0.0..0.1788.1788.8-1......0....1..gws-wiz-img.BXgpkUiMK_Q&ved=0ahUKEwj17fKX-K7mAhWUX3wKHQ7KCp8Q4dUDCAc&uact=5) to prevent the dogs from coming into the kitchen.

Many of the techniques one would use child proofing the kitchen can be applied to dog proofing the kitchen.

You can get bins specifically designed as dog proof, but as you've already mentioned it doesn't prevent them from knocking them over and attempting to get at the rubbish, so possible not as effective as actually preventing the dogs from accessing the bin itself.

Comment: 1. I don't really want to empty it every day because that would be a waste of 13 gallon bags. Or even smaller bags if you have to change them every day even if there's barely anything in there :(

2. They are tall enough to reach most places, but putting the trashcan on something would make it kinda hard to use the pedal if there is one. But I guess I could try getting a motion sensitive one. They're not really THAT committed to getting in there that they would try to knock it over, so that might work. Inside cupboards could work too, but again, smaller volume :\

Comment: 3. I don't think they'd try getting into the cupboard, but still, smaller space for trash.

4. Can't keep them out of the kitchen cuz that's where their food and water are :( And they make a giant mess with those, so can't really put them anywhere else.

But some good suggestions! I might try a raised motion sensitive trash can if this new one I just got, that has buttons and no pedal, doesn't work out.

Comment: @Raksha we have only ever used small kitchen tidies. I'm in favour of getting the trash out of the house. That solves a lot of issues. We have a kitchen tidy now. But for many year only used plastic bags we'd hang on the stove handle. Meaning it needed to be thrown away quickly and the dogs could easily raid it if they were left unsupervised. Occasionally we'd sit the bag on the kitchen bench until it was tossed out.

Answer (score 0):

Better to train your dog that the trash can is out of bounds. Use leash, take your dog to the trash can and give a No or Leave command when it tries to get into it. When it does what you want it to do praise, good dog etc. but avoid treats. You keep repeating until the message gets through. Then do the same off the leash. No doubt patience will be required.

Comment: they don't do it when I'm around :| and definitely wouldn't try to get in if i'm standing right next to them

Comment: Have you sorted this out now? My opinion, for what it is worth, is that it is always better in the longterm to get your dog to know that the trash can is out of bounds irrespective of whether you are around or not. I have always managed to achieve this with all of the dogs I have owned.  For a really excellent reputable online trainer checkout www.topcatsanddogs.home.blog. You can get plenty of free advice.

Comment: Yes, i got a motion activated trashcan and raised it on a box. For some reason, even tho they can still reach the sensor with their noses, they haven't tried getting into it yet. Maybe discouraged by the lack of foot pedal XD